# How to update a WPF Control from the TPL Task?

Tags: .net, wpf, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

How to update a WPF Control from the TPL Task?

Fine so I tried some scenarios to use Dispatcher but anyway it gives the error. I need help guys!

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)MyInit); 
        backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DoSomething1();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        backgroundDBTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            // ... UI update work here ...
        },             
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());             
    }

    void DoSomething1()
    {
        // MyInit();
        int number = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (state)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Begin second task... {0}", number++);
               // mostCommonWords = GetMostCommonWords(words) + string.Format("   Begin second task... {0}", number++);

                textBox2.Text = (number++).ToString(); // Gives the error

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(); // How it should be ?
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a delegate that does your work to `BeginInvoke`.
`BeginInvoke` will asynchronously run this delegate on the UI thread.

For example:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate {
    textBox2.Text = number.ToString(); 
}));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I just tried and it works. But I changed it to my way.    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<int>(SetStatus), number);   And I added the new method private void SetStatus(int index)
        {
            textBox2.Text = index.ToString();
        } . So thank you!

Comment: It's much easier to use anonymous methods or lambda expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I know there is already an answer here and what Slaks gave you will fix it since it will use the Dispatcher thread thus will not throw an exception for `accessing a control from a different thread`.

But, I notice this.

```
 backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            DoSomething1();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

With this

```
 backgroundDBTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        // ... UI update work here ...
    },             
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

You already have a comment where to update the UI and you also gave it the `SynchronizationContext`. Why are you still trying to update the `UI` inside of your `DoSomething1`?

Unless your purpose of your `Task` is to update the `UI` then there is no need to use the `ContinueWith`. Instead just pass the `SynchronizationContext` and it should work without having to explicitly call the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

```
backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            DoSomething1();
        },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```