# WPF Pressing Enter Key How to Make Button look pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ok, this is driving me nuts.  I have a simple WPF login app that has a login button that I want to be clicked if the user hits the enter key on the keyboard.  Here is the catch, I want the button to look like it has been pressed when the user hits enter.

I use IsDefault = true; and it will login however the button never changes as it is processing.

xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="SignInButton" Click="SignInButton_Click" Margin="277,523,265,-125"      MaxWidth="100" MinWidth="100" IsDefault="False"  Style="{StaticResource SignInButton}">
                    <Button.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="6"
                                              BlurRadius="6"
                                              Opacity="1"
                                              Direction="315"
                                              Color="gray" />
                    </Button.Effect>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="Connect"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Connect" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,2,0,0"/>
```

I have even tried to just change the text:

```
    private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Connect.Focus();

            Connect.Text = "Please Wait...";

            SignInButton.IsDefault = true;

        }
    }
```

Again, this works but the text does not change until after the button has processed.

Comment: Did you also set the IsDefault property on the login button, or do you only set this on the OnKeyDownHandler?

Comment: Nate, I tried it both ways and got the same result.

Comment: it's because you're doing it on the main UI thread.  Create a `BackgroundWorker` thread to do the processing.

Comment: Assuming that you want the text to update regardless of whether the user clicked the button, or pressed enter: then you don't need to write an OnKeyDownHandler at all.  Instead, do all your UI work in the SignInButton_Click.

Comment: What do you mean with "until after the button has processed", and "as it is processing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to simulate this behavior, since by default this is not visually updated, just the actions executed.

This is how I am provoking the visual update:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnswer001.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window4" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFDDDDDD" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.4">
                                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFAA3737"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Text="TextBlock"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Margin="0,0,26,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"><Run Text="TextBlock"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Margin="0,0,26,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Content="Login" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" IsDefault="True" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

public partial class Window4 : Window
{
    public Window4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateButtonVisualState();
        LoginProcessing();
    }

    private async Task LoginProcessing()
    {
        // Simulating a long background task.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }

    private async Task UpdateButtonVisualState()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(LoginButton, "Pressed", useTransitions: true);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(LoginButton, "Normal", useTransitions: true);
    }
}
```

No need to handle the enter key since this is the default button.

Comment: I only needed the `UpdateButtonVisualState()` method, I did not have to alter my XAML. This was awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code of your `SignInButton_Click` event handler?

It should be running it's long-running task on the background thread, otherwise your button will not change until this method has completed and the UI has been updated.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are tying up the UI thread.  Setting Connect.Text = "Please Wait..." will not take effect until after the UI thread has been freed up, and it can go do work like redrawing the UI.  You either need to explicitly refresh the screen, or use some kind of asynchronous pattern to do work.  I recommend the latter.

There are loads of articles about how to do asynchronous work in WPF.  Try searching for terms like "WPF background worker" or "WPF async await" or "WPF Task.Factory.StartNew"  odds are, that just by posting this the "related" links bar on the side will show some.

Edit: Some links for you, showing different approaches.

[Async Attempt WPF Blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838147/async-attempt-wpf-blocking)

[How to update a WPF Control from the TPL Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726697/how-to-update-a-wpf-control-from-the-tpl-task)